# Access es2015 class function member

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```js
'use strict';

class Test {
    lorem () {

    }

    static ipsum () {

    }
}

console.log(Test.lorem); // undefined
console.log(Test.ipsum); [Function]
```

Is there a way to access Test.lorem? I've tried Test.prototype.lorem and Test.lorem but both return undefined.

The constructor of the function I want to test does some constructor-like things, so in the unit test I just want to run the function directly from the class instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Test.prototype.lorem` should not return undefined:  https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lorem%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20ipsum%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(Test.prototype.lorem)%3B%20%2F%2F%20undefined%0D%0Aalert(Test.ipsum)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5BFunction%5D%20

Comment: NOTE: This REPL is still using Babel 5.x but will be upgraded to Babel 6 very soon!

This is not spec behaviour. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is available in the `prototype`.

```
Test.prototype.lorem
```

However, remember that calling this method directly means than `this` will will not refer to an instance of the object.

`Test.lorem` is undefined, because it is not a static method. Non-static methods are added to the `prototype` object.

Proof compiled from Babel 6 with the ES2015 preset.

```js
'use strict';

var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Test);
    }

    _createClass(Test, [{
        key: 'lorem',
        value: function lorem() {}
    }], [{
        key: 'ipsum',
        value: function ipsum() {}
    }]);

    return Test;
})();

console.log(Test.prototype.lorem);
```

Comment: Half correct... They are added to the prototype but they are not available there; see my answer.

Comment: @lededje See the code snippet I added, and check your developer console. Using Babel 6 with the ES2015 preset, I don't have any problems accessing the method form the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't execute a method without an instance unless it's a static member.

This is a very fundamental concept in most (if not all) object oriented languages.

If you only want to get a reference of the function, using the class prototype does work.

As an aside, you actually *can* execute method without an instance since JavaScript does allow this flexibility but fwiw you should avoid such practices.

Comment: Really? I thought that `class` syntax was a just constraining sugar over the existing prototype system which did allow this. Interesting...

Comment: @JeremyBanks is correct, you can access the function through the prototype.

Comment: Yeah -- this answer is wrong. Maybe the OP is mistaken about his own code, or Babel is producing non-standard behaviour. I just executed this non-static method through its prototype using Chrome's native implementation as `Test.prototype.lorem()` and it worked as I expected.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - yes you can *access* the function, but you should have an instance of you plan to call it. Perhaps my answer isn't clear enough on this point.

Comment: The reason for executing methods without an instance is for testing purposes.

Comment: @JeremyBanks "or Babel is producing non-standard behaviour" It's creating spec correct behaviour. See my answer.

Comment: @lededje - if you have a non static method and you call it without an instance it should fail. If *that's* what your testing then I'd say it's an odd test, but you're allowed to do so. Otherwise, there's no point in this type of test

Comment: @Amit Why should it fail? Unit testing a single function member of a class is good practice.

Comment: @lededje - If its a non-static member function it should depend on some instance and some state. This means that *without* an instance it will fail. If on the other hand it *doesn't* depend on any state, it shouldn't be a member function, or at most be a static function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98273/discussion-between-lededje-and-amit).

Answer (score -1):

You need an instance to `Test`.

```
class Test {
      lorem () {
        console.log('test');
      }

      static ipsum () {

      }
  }

  var test = new Test();
  test.lorem();
```

Or you can do

```
Test.prototype.lorem();
```

Comment: Not the case; See my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why I got a -1 but w/e

## Class Methods Are Non-Enumerable in ES2015

You can't directly access class members that are not static.

https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T959

Comment: Even if it's not enumerable, it should still be accessible.

Comment: Apparently not, trying to find this in the official spec.

Comment: As far as I can see, the link talks about how `console.log(Foo.prototype);` was producing `{ bar: [Function: bar] }`, rather than `{}`, which is a completely separate issue. Check out the snippet in my answer.

Comment: Again, not what I'm seeing. This gist give me a before and after, version in the title.

https://gist.github.com/lededje/7fda648db11b0e26dddd

Comment: That's because you're test is flawed. Try adding `console.log(Test.prototype.lorem);` to `test.js`, and it will work. It's not a static method, so it goes in the prototype.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, apologies are in order; you were right. I'm not sure what I was doing before but I was sure I tried prototype a number of times with no success. Up voted your answer and marked it as correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us. :)